# How to show <div> from code behind in PageLoad after some criteria asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an issue because when i reload data from my base i check if there is some value that should show me a div.

When that criteria is met (i chose value that should show me a div) it works. Problem is when i want reload data that was saved.

my function in front

```
<script>
     function showDivOrHide(dd_status) {
           if (dd_status.value == 'Met criteria') {
                 $('#someDiv').show(300);
                 }
           else {
              $('#someDiv').hide(300);
           }

  }
</script>
```

And my code in PageLoad:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
....

string status = customer["STATUS"].ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status)){

      dd_status.SelectedValue = status;
      if(status.Equals("Met criteria")){
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "showDivOrHide(" + dd_status + ")", true);
 }


....
}
```

So how to load JS function from PageLoad? Is there any possibility?

Comment: There is no question here or at least it's not clear

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option, I'd suggest you to use Webservices (Generic Handlers).
Then it's possible to pass your values, which you need to evaluate, to this webserivce.

```
   function validateSelection(customerStatus) {
     $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "url/to/webservice" + "?status=" + customerStatus,
      success: function (data) {
         var status = data.status;
         if(status === true){ 
           // show your div 
         } else {
           // do smth else
         }

      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // error handling
      }
    });
   }
```

Whereas your webservice code could contain your validation and simply return the data as JSON:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if(dd_status == context.Request.QueryString["status"]){
      context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
      context.Response.Write("{ \"status\": true }");
    } else {
      context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
      context.Response.Write("{ \"status\": false}");
    }
}
```

This is how far I understood your question.